# mongodb: Can I create an unshard Replica set for a sharded cluster?

Tags: replication, mongodb

I have a 3 node shard cluster mongoDB with replica set, and want to add (single node replica set) a un-sharded Replica set to collect all data in one node.

Can I create an unshard Replica set for a sharded cluster?

Comment: Can you edit your question with more detail on what you are trying to achieve? For example, is your goal to backup your sharded cluster to a single node replica set or perhaps add another shard for unsharded collections?

Answer (score 0):

> mongodb: Can I create an unshard Replica set for a sharded cluster?

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-shard-standalone-to-shard-replica-set/) Starting in MongoDB 3.6, all shards must be replica sets. Before you can upgrade your 3.4 sharded cluster to version 3.6, you must convert any shards that are running as standalone mongod instances to replica set shards.

> **Note:** To converts a standalone shard to a single-member replica set shard. The procedure assumes that the
>   single member runs on the same host and port as before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have 2 replica set for each shard and I want collect all data in one single node replica and use it as another independent mongodb Database without timeout in my site